# Firebase - Firestore data query callled twice two times In web version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to do a query in which I get all of the documents from orders collection in firestore database. But there is a problem that all of the data is duplicated instead of getting one row for each document is duplicated. Is there any solution to that problem? I have attached the code.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell, { tableCellClasses } from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import { db } from "../../config/Config";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.min";

const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell)(({ theme }) => ({
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.head}`]: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
  },
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.body}`]: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
}));

const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow)(({ theme }) => ({
  "&:nth-of-type(odd)": {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
  },
  // hide last border
  "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": {
    border: 0,
  },
}));

function createData(
  id,
  DateOfInquiry,
  CompanyName,
  ContactPerson,
  ContactNo,
  ContactEmail,
  Model,
  Type,
  Capacity,
  Quantity,
  DeliveryLocation,
  WorkStartDate,
  LoadingLocation,
  UnloadingLocation,
  Comments
) {
  return {
    id,
    DateOfInquiry,
    CompanyName,
    ContactPerson,
    ContactNo,
    ContactEmail,
    Model,
    Type,
    Capacity,
    Quantity,
    DeliveryLocation,
    WorkStartDate,
    LoadingLocation,
    UnloadingLocation,
    Comments,
  };
}

const rows = [];

export default function CustomizedTables() {
  const [newProduct, setNewProduct] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    return db
      .collection("Orders")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const ProductData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }));
        setNewProduct(ProductData);
      });
  }, []);
  newProduct.forEach((doc) => {
    rows.push(
      createData(
        doc.id,
        doc.DateOfInquiry,
        doc.CompanyName,
        doc.ContactPerson,
        doc.ContactNo,
        doc.ContactEmail,
        doc.Model,
        doc.Type,
        doc.Capacity,
        doc.Quantity,
        doc.DeliveryLocation,
        doc.WorkStartDate,
        doc.LoadingLocation,
        doc.UnloadingLocation,
        doc.Comments
      )
    );
  });
  const history = useHistory();
  const [ButtonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);
  const handelClick = (e) => {
    db.collection("Orders").doc(e.target.value).delete();
    setNewProduct([]);
    setButtonClicked(!ButtonClicked);
    history.push("/table");
  };
  /* useEffect(() => {
    return db
      .collection("Orders")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const ProductData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }));
        setNewProduct(ProductData);
      });
  }, [ButtonClicked]); */

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 700 }} aria-label="customized table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Checkbox</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">S.no</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Date of Inquiry</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Company Name</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Contact Person</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Contact No</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Contact Email</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Model</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Type</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Capacity</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Quantity</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Delivery Location</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Work Start Date</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Loading Location</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Unloadig Location</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Comments</StyledTableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row) => (
            <StyledTableRow key={row.id} onClick={handelClick}>
              <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                <Checkbox
                  color="primary"
                  value={row.id}
                  onChange={handelClick}
                />
              </TableCell>
              <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.id}
              </StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">
                {row.DateOfInquiry}
              </StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.CompanyName}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">
                {row.ContactPerson}
              </StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.ContactNo}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">
                {row.ContactEmail}
              </StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.Model}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.Type}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.Capacity}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.Quantity}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">
                {row.DeliveryLocation}
              </StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">
                {row.WorkStartDate}
              </StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">
                {row.LoadingLocation}
              </StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">
                {row.UnloadingLocation}
              </StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.Comments}</StyledTableCell>
            </StyledTableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

This is the image of the table.

[image: Table Image]

Comment: As far as I understand, in the initial render, your useEffect hook fetches documents from firestore and sets the data in setNewProduct array( which was initially an empty array). Now if you want to show the data in table UI, why not call {this.id, this.DateOfInquiry, this.CompanyName, this.ContactPerson, this.ContactNo, this.ContactEmail in the table tags( as you are using setState methods) instead of again pushing the data in an array 'rows' and using rows.id, rows.DateOfInquiry, rows.CompanyName, rows.ContactPerson, rows.ContactNo.

Comment: Can you please check my previous comment and confirm if you have tried it?

Comment: Did you try working on the comment I posted?

Comment: yes I forgot to remove the question cause I already have solved. the problem

Comment: Please delete the question if you solved it or may be you can post the answer here for others going through the same issue?